# JUnit/Java: How to enforce a thread to yield?

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit, concurrency

I'm trying to write a bugfix pr which contains a test that shows current code is buggy.

In that test, I would like to show that under certain circumstances, current code breaks. To show that, I need to make one thread to yield at particular execution point.

Below is a brief illustration of current code.

```java
private boolean accessible = false;
private boolean field = false;

// THREAD 1:
boolean accessible = true;
/*
   do something
*/
field = true;
// end of thread 1

// THREAD 2:
if (accessible) {
    assertTrue(field);
}
// end of thread 2
```

Normally, thread 2 starts way later than thread 1. However, sometimes, thread 2 starts when thread 1 has executed `accessible = true` but not yet `field = true`.

My problem here is that, I'm new to JUnit, and I do not know how to consistently reproduce above execution order.

If I can force thread 1 to `yield` at some point, I think I can consistently reproduce the problem, but I failed to find a way to.

Can someone tell me a way to consistently reproduce above concurrency issue?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare boolean variables accessible and field as volatile so as the other thread sees the updated value of these.

And then use a combination of yield and sleep in Thread1 after variable accessible is set to true;

```
private volatile boolean accessible = false;
private volatile boolean field = false;

// THREAD 1:
accessible = true;
/*
   do something
*/
try
{ 
    //Allow thread 1 to sleep for 2000 milliseconds. this makes sure thread2 gets started.
    Thread.sleep(1000); 
} catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println(e); 
} 
Thread.yield(); // this will allow other threads (with same or higher priority) to run. By now thread2 must have been started.

field = true;
// end of thread 1

// THREAD 2:
if (accessible) {
    assertTrue(field);
}
// end of thread 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer, however, what I'm trying to do is to demonstrate the original code is buggy by providing a "test code", not by modifying the original code. I cannot modify the original code. thanks.

Comment: I am afraid if you can not modify the source code, then **showing always that the code is buggy;** in your test case is _not possible_ because in reality the code can run correct and code can run wrong. So , showing always the test to fail is practically not possible without modifying the source or tempering with the working of source code (by calling some method on thread1/thread2 at runtime).

Comment: There is one thing of course you can do, run your test 100 times in a for loop until your test fails for 1 of the iteration. This way you can show the developer that the code can behave strangely when it is run ;) !

Comment: See here for yield() https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-yield